# How can I list all the outdated NuGet packages in my solution with the indication how old are they

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm working on the big enterprise application, where automatic updates of packages is problematic.

I would like to start updating them manually, but I want to know the priority: I want to start from the most outdated ones, where the difference between release date of the latest stable version and the version I'm using is the biggest.

Is there a script or tool that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your solution.
2. Open the Nuget Package Manager Console.
3. Run this PowerShell script:

   ```ps
   #Creates a CSV file of Packages in your solution which have updates available.
   Get-Package -Updates | Select-Object -Property ID -ExpandProperty Versions | Select-Object -Property ID, Major, Minor, Patch, Revision | Export-Csv -Path UpdatesAvailable.csv -NoTypeInformation                                               
   #Creates a CSV file of all the Packages in your solution
   Get-Package | Select-Object -Property ID, ProjectName -ExpandProperty Versions | Select-Object -Property ID, ProjectName, Major, Minor, Patch, Revision | Export-Csv -Path Installed.csv -NoTypeInformation
   ```
4. Start Excel and import the CSV files with Power Query. This should result in two Queries we'll call "Installed" and "Merged."
5. Create a Merge query from "Installed" and "Merged" and join on "Id"
6. In Excel, add 3 columns next to the resulting table labeled "MajorDiff", "MinorDiff" and "PatchDiff."
7. In each column, add a formula like this:

   ```
   =MAX([@[Latest.Major]]-[@[Installed.Major]],0)
   ```
8. Finally, calculate a Weighted Diff:

   ```
   =([@MajorDiff]*100) + ([@MinorDiff]*10) + [@PatchDiff]
   ```

Now you know which projects use which outdated Package and how severely those packages are out of date.

Comment: As I understand I will show difference of versions, not of dates? This is not bad, but diff in dates can be more interesting, because different packages have different tempo of updates...